# Имя словаря не существует

Tags: c#, словари

Не могу понять в чём причина. Пишет, что имя appUsers не существует в текущем контексте. В чём может быть причина?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace namespace1
{
    class Users
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> appUsers = new();
        appUsers.Add()
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ошибка возникает потому, что вы пытаетесь писать код внутри класса, а не внутри его методов.

Comment: Большое спасибо!